# Find MAX value from a JOIN query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I have the following two tables:

**Table #USER**

```
SELECT *
INTO #USER
FROM (
    SELECT 'A.2017.JAN' AS [KSCEN], 'John' AS [Name], 'Doe' AS [Surname] UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A.2017.JAN' AS [KSCEN], 'Paul' AS [Name], 'Red' AS [Surname] UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A.2017.FEB' AS [KSCEN], 'John' AS [Name], 'Doe' AS [Surname] UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A.2017.FEB' AS [KSCEN], 'Paul' AS [Name], 'Red' AS [Surname] UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A.2017.MAR' AS [KSCEN], 'John' AS [Name], 'Doe' AS [Surname] UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A.2017.MAR' AS [KSCEN], 'Paul' AS [Name], 'Red' AS [Surname] UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A.2017.MAR' AS [KSCEN], 'Kate' AS [Name], 'Blue' AS [Surname]
) A
```

**Table #KSCEN**

```
SELECT *
INTO #KSCEN
FROM (
    SELECT 'A.2017.JAN' AS [ID], 6 AS [SEQ] UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A.2017.FEB' AS [ID], 7 AS [SEQ] UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A.2017.MAR' AS [ID], 8 AS [SEQ] UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A.2017.APR' AS [ID], 9 AS [SEQ] UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A.2017.MAY' AS [ID], 10 AS [SEQ]
) A
```

My goal is to find the element of #KSCEN with the MAX SEQ that is used at least one times inside table #USER.
I got it with the following subquery and LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT [ID]
FROM #KSCEN
WHERE [SEQ] = (SELECT MAX(B.[SEQ]) FROM #USER A LEFT JOIN #KSCEN B ON A.[KSCEN]=B.[ID])
```

This works but consider that table #USER, in my case, contains more than 30,000,000 rows so it is not very fast to solve the query as the system need to join every rows and then find the MAX.

Is there a more efficent way to solve my problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because optimization questions belong on CodeReview.

Comment: @ScottHunter Questions marked with the [query-optimization] tag are very on topic here and have a respectable following of people who answer such questions on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid that `correlated subquery` you have used in the where clause. It produces a "row by agonizing row" effect as each row of the from/where clause gets tested against a MAX() calculation, one new query for each row.

Without the benefit of real tables to use, or execution plans, I suggest the following:

You can try it at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/9786)

**Query 1**:

```
with tUSER as 
(
    SELECT 'A.2017.JAN' AS [KSCEN], 'John' AS [Name], 'Doe' AS [Surname] UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A.2017.JAN' AS [KSCEN], 'Paul' AS [Name], 'Red' AS [Surname] UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A.2017.FEB' AS [KSCEN], 'John' AS [Name], 'Doe' AS [Surname] UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A.2017.FEB' AS [KSCEN], 'Paul' AS [Name], 'Red' AS [Surname] UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A.2017.MAR' AS [KSCEN], 'John' AS [Name], 'Doe' AS [Surname] UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A.2017.MAR' AS [KSCEN], 'Paul' AS [Name], 'Red' AS [Surname] UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A.2017.MAR' AS [KSCEN], 'Kate' AS [Name], 'Blue' AS [Surname]
) 
, tKSCEN as  (
    SELECT 'A.2017.JAN' AS [ID], 6 AS [SEQ] UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A.2017.FEB' AS [ID], 7 AS [SEQ] UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A.2017.MAR' AS [ID], 8 AS [SEQ] UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A.2017.APR' AS [ID], 9 AS [SEQ] UNION ALL
    SELECT 'A.2017.MAY' AS [ID], 10 AS [SEQ]
)
SELECT U.[KSCEN], MAX(K.[SEQ])  max_seq
FROM tUSER U 
LEFT JOIN tKSCEN K ON U.[KSCEN]=K.[ID]
GROUP BY U.[KSCEN]
;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/9786/0)**:

```
|      KSCEN | max_seq |
|------------|---------|
| A.2017.FEB |       7 |
| A.2017.JAN |       6 |
| A.2017.MAR |       8 |
```